# Issue with Rstudio version (Version 1.3.1073) "Giant goldenrod" when moving R studio window to new monitor doesn't display correctly

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, dpi

This is a basic question that I hope has a simple solution. When I move my Rstudio window to an external monitor display - it no longer rescales properly and instead is rendered completely useless - showing me only the lower portion of the window (see screenshot) and doesn't allow me to resize the window or adjust it in anyway to access the taskbar along the top. Has anyone else experienced this or have options for how this could be fixed?

I frequently need to shift my Rstudio window to different monitors, and I was doing this with no issue prior to installing the latest Rstudio version - so I am wondering if there must just be some setting that got reset when I updated the software, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have tried fixing scaling options in Windows by using the properties options on the Rstudio icon on my desktop - and then clicking on compatibility and High DPI settings, but messing around with that so far hasn't seemed to work. However I haven't tried all possible combinations as i thought I would check here first to see if someone could fast track this process for me. As you can see in the image - this display is impossible to work with. When I move it back - it works as it should. I am using Windows 10, and I update my software regularly. TY!

[image: Clip of screen with Rstudio improperly displayed]

Comment: This is still happening, and I've just been living with it - despite the fact that I have the latest R studio and R version, and I have tried all possible options for display settings! Helpppp, I hate not being able to work in a bigger screen.

Comment: Have you tried these steps: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2872#issuecomment-461118957

Comment: That *pretty much* solves it - thank you! The primary issue here, is that if I move the Rstudio window from the external monitor with a higher display resolution back to my regular laptop screen, it is a little blurry. But this is something I can work with! Having it visible on my external monitor is worth that. If anyone knows how to make it crisp on either screen though, would love to hear it. Thank you!

Comment: @JadaLovelace - propose this as an answer and I would be willing to award you the bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

Ok, I was able to reproduce on a Lenovo with an external Dell monitor and address the problem by applying a fix proposed in another Stack Overflow thread. See below:

Research:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-scaling-issues-for-high-dpi-devices-508483cd-7c59-0d08-12b0-960b99aa347d

#### Resolution:

There is a solution, it comes from the option "Compatibility" of the execute file.

- Close all current RStudio windows.
- Right-click on the shortcut of RStudio (or the original .exe file) and choose Properties
- [image: List item]
- In the RStudio Properties pop-up windows, choose the tab Compatibility
- Select **High DPI settings**
- [image]
- Tick on option **Override hide DPI scaling...** and then choose **System** from the drop-down list.
- [image]
- Apply > OK.
- (Re)open Rstudio to see the change

On my test system, this addressed the problem observed where the menu text became super large.

### Stackoverflow original reference:

- [RStudio HiDPI support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828295/rstudio-hidpi-support/31062004)

---

This appears to be an issue with the version of QT used by RStudio. RStudio is built on top of the QT engine.

QT tracking Issue:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48242

the issue is marked as fixed in QT version 5.9.0 and above.

**Recommendation:**

Download RStudio preview and try that:

https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

Why? The preview version of RStudio appears to use  **QtWebEngine/5.12.8**, which implies the issue is addressed. If that does not resolve the issue you could file a bug with RStudio, or install and recompile RStudio from the source with an updated version of QT. You can check your QT version via the help, about box.

[image]

Hoping the above points you in the right direction. Stays safe and well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the sole source of the problem, as I was still having this issue before I followed the steps outlined by @JadaLovelace  above. Here is my current help screen (keep in mind that I've updated Rstudio since I first posted this question):

Comment: Current version via help screen: 

Version 1.4.1717
© 2009-2021 RStudio, PBC
"Juliet Rose" (df86b69e, 2021-05-24) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

Comment: @Brewkeeper Thanks for the update, let me go check a few things...

Comment: @Brewkeeper I updated the answer to reflect the solution I used after testing on a Windows machine. Hope this solves the problem for you two.